# Is there a circuit element which dissipates energy but does not act as a resistor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, resistors, power-engineering

I know this sounds a bit weird, but is there a circuit elements which dissipates energy if a current flows through it but is not a resistor?

In other words, is there an energy sink which does not alter the properties of the circuit?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Inductors, capacitors and antennas can dissipate power by coupling with something outside the circuit.

Comment: If the question happens to be a logic trick I'll answer "yes, there is one! It's the air gap." It fulfills the logic condition (=dissipates IF it conducts current). It doesn't conduct, so it doesn't disturb the circuit. Think for ex. the gap between two copper lines. Making a new gap in the middle of an existing wire affects, but the effect is caused by the gap maker, not the gap which didn't even exist.

Comment: @Christian:  What are you trying to do?  You are asking about a component that you think will solve your problem rather than asking how to solve your problem.  You have a solution that appears to require liberal use of unobtanium.  Maybe there's another solution that can be made with real components and materials.

Comment: but they still appear as "resistance" to the circuit. Just because you go via some other means doesn't change the fact energy is being dissipated and thus resolving the resultant equations realises an equivalent R.

Comment: Fundamentally, the answer is NO. You are talking about removing energy from the system, so the system can't stay unaltered by nature. However, this question looks like it's more about something specific than you don't care to tell. If you mean simply that it doesn't behave like a FIXED resistor, then a diode, transistor circuits (including just 1 transistor), they all can and will dissipare very different amount of energy based on different criteria. There are things like current sinks etc. Your question is very vague.

Comment: Energy cannot be destroyed but converted to heat by resistance or converted to charge an inductor or capacitor. Semiconductors may act as resistance.

Comment: There are plenty of components that dissipate energy, but aren't resistors.  An LED is one.  But how can you have something that dissipates energy, but doesn't alter the circuit?  That sounds like the basis for a perpetual motion machine.

Comment: Yes! LEDs and motors are not pure resistors : one emits light, the other, mechanical energy (and both emit some heat) while the resistor emits pure heat. And NO! Both "alter the properties of the circuit" ... so you 'll need to be a bit clearer what you're looking for.

Comment: Original question... that provokes original answers...

Comment: @BrianDrummond excellent examples...I'd add "antenna". One component of its equivalent resistance is energy lost to the environment. Similar to "LED" or lightbulb.

Answer (score 2):

If you will (hopefully) recall your complex impedance plane and the formula:

$$Z = R + jX$$

\$Z\$, obviously, is the impedance and it's a complex number because representing this as a complex number conveniently fits the mathematics.

\$R\$ is the "real" resistance and \$X\$ is the "reactance".

In the real world \$R\$ comes from resistance elements and \$X\$ comes from inductance and capacitance.  This chart shows what this might look like plotted on the complex number plane:

[image: Wikipedia Complex Number Graph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance#/media/File:Complex_Impedance.svg]

While both \$R\$ and \$X\$ are measurable quantities, any amount along the imaginary axis is not dissipated as heat from the system.  It stays in the system indefinitely.  In an idea system it circulates or oscillates forever.  (There are real-world examples that approach this.  Think of the superconducting coil, or inductor, in an MRI machine.  This is a pure reactive load and an electrical current, once started when the machine is installed, basically circulates forever.  Well, not really forever but for a very long time.  There is effectively ZERO resistance in a superconductor to dissipate the energy.)

It's only along the real axis that energy gets dissipated, and this is what we call resistance.

In a real-world system there are many ways that energy gets removed from the system and the most common is heat.  But it could also be a motor that removes it as mechanical energy, an LED that removes it as light energy, a transducer/speaker that removes it as sound energy, etc.  These other things are not "resistors" but they have a component in the real direction that makes them look either fully or partially as a resistor for circuit analysis purposes.

So to answer your questions:

> ...is there a circuit element[s] which dissipates energy if a current flows
> through it but is not a resistor

Yes, as noted above along with many many other devices that remove energy from a system.  But ALL of them have a Re component.  If they don't then they don't act like a resistor at all.

> is there an energy sink which does not alter the properties of the
> circuit

This is a VERY different question that is, IMHO, unrelated to your first question.  But the answer is NO, such a device does not exist.  In fact ANY device you place in a circuit alters the properties of that circuit in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You ask two different questions...they are not equivalent.

If you are asking about **ideal** circuit elements, then any voltage or current source can consume power. Current flowing into the positive terminal of an ideal voltage source will cause that element to consume power.

Is there any element that can sink energy from a circuit without altering the properties of a circuit? No, that is clearly impossible on its face.

Comment: And where does this power (consumed by the source) go in the end?

Comment: If it's an **ideal** element then we do not care. If it is a real element that resembles a voltage source, then the power can be converted to heat, or light, or chemical energy. A charging battery is reasonably well modeled as an ideal voltage source that consumes power.

Comment: I think that whether it is ideal or real is not so important (in the latter case, only part of the energy will be dissipated in its internal resistance). The question is fundamental and it is more important whether the source is reversible - for example, a motor (dynamo), speaker (microphone)... and a special case is a rechargeable battery. In these cases, the energy consumed will be converted into the appropriate form. I wonder what happens when the source is not reversible. For example, what will happen if we connect an ordinary battery in series and in an opposite direction to the main one?

Comment: The distinction between ideal and non-ideal is critically important, I will not let that go. You propose a vaguely worded experiment when you describe an "ordinary battery". You will need to clarify the meaning of the question by showing me how the battery would be modeled as a set of ideal components. In general I think this is a chemistry question, and is outside my area of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

> ... is there an energy sink which does not alter the properties of the circuit?

Yes, there is such a "sink"; its name is "transimpedance amplifier" - Fig. 1a. In this conceptual circuit diagram, the op-amp output is represented by the variable voltage sourve VOA.

[image: Transimpedance amplifier - concept]

Fig. 1. Transimpedance amplifier - a conceptual circuit diagram (circled in blue).

It consists of two elements in series - a resistor R2 and a variable voltage source (a properly supplied op-amp) that copies the voltage drop VR2 across the resistor and adds it to VR2. As a result, the voltage between the two circuit terminals (op-amp inputs) is zero (VR2 - VOA = VR2 - VR2 = 0)... and the circuit (circled in blue) behaves just as a "piece of wire" - Fig. 1b.

The resistor R2 dissipates power but the op-amp adds the same power; so "this sink does not alter the properties of the circuit" (VIN, R1)... as you want. The current is I = VIN/R1 whether or not this "sink" is inserted...